# Copy & paste of text from OneNote (for Mac) to OneNote is EXTREMELY SLOW, while copying from outside remains fast

Tags: macos, performance, copy-paste, microsoft-onenote

Copy & paste of even small snippets of text from WITHIN OneNote to the same or another page WITHIN OneNote is EXTREMELY SLOW.

Oddly, when copying text from OUTSIDE of OneNote, e.g. from Chrome or Word, into OneNote, it works as fast as it should.

While pasting text copied from the same page of OneNote, a popup saying “Please wait…” will open. Sometimes OneNote will hang for just 1-2s, sometimes it can hangup completely and needs a “Force quit”.

This occurs with even very small snippets of text, e.g., just a single word.

This also occurs if I paste via OneNotes “Paste” menu - no matter which of the paste options (“Keep text only” etc.) I use - I tried them all.

I am using OneNote for Mac sind 2018 and the issue started to occur around end of 2021. First, the delay was barely recognisable, but now it started to affect usability severely. MacOS version 12.2.1.

I have found many people (e.g., [1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8063051), [2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/officeinsider/forum/all/why-is-pasting-in-onenote-mac-from-external/cb4aa266-0df5-492a-94ce-c620dc28c4cb) ) complaining about slow copy & paste in OneNote, but their issue seems to be related to copying from OUTSIDE of OneNote (which works well for me) and could sometimes be solved by pasting with the option "Keep text only", which does not help in my case.